# Issue with navigating from modal page to main page in Ionic

Tags: ionic3

I am new to ionic. I have a main page which contains three ionic segments. Each segment is having two divs. In the first segment we have two divs where first div is a list and upon clicking a list element second div will open (details page of clicked list element).

In the second div I have a button. upon click of that button a modal should open which has a list of items and you have to select an item from the list and send the item name and item id to second div in my main page.

The problem which I am facing is when I enter the page I have made the list div as my default page so when i navigate back from modal to main page instead of loading second div my first div is loading and I am not able to fetch the item name and item id from modal.

Please help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Create a handler when the modal closes.

When creating a modal,

```
goOnModal(){
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(YourModal);
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => {
        console.log(data); //just a checker

        // store in a variable
        this.dataFromModal = data;
    });
    modal.present();
}
```

On modal component, call dismiss() to close the modal and go back to the main page

```
dismiss(){
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(
        // your data that will be returned
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how we can pass the data from modal to div2 of segment1 of page 1? My page1 has 3 different segments and I want to pass the data to div2 of segment1 of page1 from modal.

Comment: details page is a div in segment 1 of page 1. This detail page has a button when we click on that button modal will open. You will select a list item and pass the data back to detail page which is a div in segment1 of page 1

Comment: That is exactly my answer to your comment/post. When you click your div2 > button, call the function that will create the modal. Refer to my answer on how to create a modal and include a handler for your data. On the modal itself, create a function that will be called when you close the modal. Let's call it `dismiss()`. Inside that, you will pass the data. Back to your  `page1 > segment1 > div2`, present the data stored in a variable .

Comment: I am facing one issue now. Initially when page1 loads first time I am making div1 visible  and hiding div2 ( both will be in segment1) . When we pass the data back from modal to page1> segment1> div2  the page is getting refreshed and it is coming to div1 by default . I want to hide div1 on page refresh and I want to show div2 with new data. How can we do this?

Comment: How to pass the data back from modal to page1 in ionic without reloading the entire page? If we use navcontrollers and navparams the entire page 1 is getting refreshed but I just want to refresh a div in page1 and I dont want to reload entire page1. How we can do this in ionic 3?